# How to do not send @IdClass object in Spring JSON queries

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm setting a server to get a CRUD api from a postgresql Database using JPA. Everytime I want to expose an object from the DB it duplicate the idObject.

When I get an object from the database using springframework and send it after that, it duplicate the idObject like this:

```
{
    "siteId": 3,
    "contractId": "1",
    "name": "sitenumber1",
    "siteIdObject": {
        "siteId": 3,
        "contractId": "1"
    }
}
```

SiteId and contractId are repeating...
but I want something like that:

```
{
    "siteId": 3,
    "contractId": "1",
    "name": "sitenumber1"
}
```

I want to avoid using DTO because I think there is a better way but I don't find it. Since I'm using springFramework for just one or two month I'm maybe forgeting something...

there is the code:

Site code:

```java
@Entity 
@IdClass(SiteId.class)
@Table(name = "site", schema="public")
public class Site {

    @Id
    @Column(name="siteid")
    private Integer siteId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="clientid")
    private Integer contractId;

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "site")
    public Set<Device> devices;

//setter, getter, hash, equals, tostring, constructor empty one and full one
```

SiteId code:

```java
public class SiteId implements Serializable {

    private Integer siteId; 
    private Integer contractId;

// setter, getter, constructor empty and full, hash and equals
```

Thanks to help :)
Bessaix Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring you might also be using Jackson so if you annotate your `SiteId`class with [@JsonIgnoreType](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreType.html) it shouldn't be serialized at all when the `Site` object is serialized.

I am however unsure if this will break your application logic now that the id object is not serialized anymore.

Comment: Wow, it was so simple, I'm happy and frustrated at the same time!
Thank you very much!